# The use of "should" and "but" in "who should he see but Whillie"

Tags: meaning

> He came to the corner where the carton was, and who **should** he see **but**
>   Whillie.

What is the meaning of *should* and *but* here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nice question. It's an odd, and slightly old-fashioned, idiom.

It means "He saw Willie", but with a strong connotation of surprise.

I don't find it easy to analyse and explain, but I think it stands for something like the following:

> Who was it that he saw at the corner? Surprise! It was nobody else but Willie!"

Comment: I know the meaning,but don't know the use.I am foreigner so I can not feel it's old..

Comment: @thirtvanke As Colin Fine explained, "[should](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/should)" is used "to emphasize to a listener how striking an event is or was". You should look up a dictionary and study. :)

Comment: @Rathony: but only as a rhetorical question, in the past: "Who should he see!" "What should I find".